# How to iterate over a html file in Python to scrape wiki

Tags: python, html, json, web

I'm trying to build a small tool to scrape from the Wikipedia API.

I have a few links in an XML file (which is saved as **wikiepedia.html**) that I'd like to iterate over (line-by-line) and obtain an output which I can then json.dump.

The wikipedia.html file contains links to the Simple Wikipedia API for certain pages (there are thousands of lines in the xml file, but they're of an identical format):

What I'd like to do is be able to start off with the first line in the html file, scrape the data from the Wikipedia API and then return the desired contents as a dictionary. **I would then like to store this as a json.**

Once that's all been done, I'd then like for the script to go the second line in the html file and do the same thing, and so on (iterate over every line until it reaches the end of the html file).

Currently I can return a dictionary in the format that I want by iterating over every line (the script keeps spitting out dictionaries). However, I'm unsure of how to store each dictionary as a json during each iteration & then for the script to parse the next line in the .xml file and do the same thing.

```
For example, if I start my current script, the first line in the html file gives the following dictionary:
```

I then would like to save this as a json.

I then would like to be able to save the second dictionary that's outputted from the script as it reads the second line as another separate json and so forth.

If anyone knows how to take each dictionary that's outputted and save them as separate json files that can be uploaded to GitHub then that'd be amazing, thank you.

Comment: XML files should actually be parsed (using XPath, for example), not iterated line by line, but you're already iterating all the lines, so what's the issue? You seem to just have a plaintext file since there's no XML tags

Comment: Hmm, what I'm trying to do is output a dictionary from my script, and then save that as a single json file. 

I then want to be able to do that for all dictionaries that are outputted from the script (but every dictionary should be saved as a separate json).

Comment: Please post sample of XML file for [mcve]. Also, there is no scraping here since you are interacting with API response which is a `json` format.

Answer (score 0):

`f.readlines()` does iterate over every line. You need to remove `m` to get all lines

You could also iterate the file directly

```
with open('simplewiki.xml', 'r') as f: 
    for wiki_link in f:
        #...
```

But this assumes a standard, line-delimited text file, not actually semi-structured (X)HTML

Comment: Thanks for the response --

I tried doing the first command, but unfortunately ran into this error before I posted this which I wasn't sure how to solve: ``` File "stack_overflow.py", line 8, in <module> with urllib.request.urlopen(wiki_link) as url: File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen return opener.open(url, data, timeout) File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 515, in open req.timeout = timeout AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout' ```

Comment: With regards to the second suggestion, I am able to iterate over every line, but I was hoping to be able to convert all these dictionary outputs into separate json files:

Comment: Such as a single json file for:

{'title': 'April', 'source': 'https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/April', 'summary': "April is the fourth month of the year, and comes between March and May. It is one of four months to have 30 days.\nApril always begins on the same day of week as July, and additionally, January in leap years. April always ends on the same day of the week as December.\nApril's flowers are the Sweet Pea and Daisy. Its birthstone is the diamond. The meaning of the diamond is innocence."}

Comment: If you're able to get one url working (i.e create a [mcve]) I suggest extracting that functionality out into a function, then looping over your list to call that function. I'm not sure on your first error because you'd be opening a url string to create a request, not passing a list